# GEO Meta Tags: When should I use them and when should I not use them? May it be even harmful?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, geolocation, geotagging

According to various sources GEO Meta Tags are ignored by the standard Google search. Example for GEO Meta Tags:

```
<meta name=”geo.region” content=”DE-BY” />
<meta name=”geo.placename” content=”M&uuml;nchen” />
<meta name=”geo.position” content=”48.169822;11.601171″ />
<meta name=”ICBM” content=”48.169822, 11.601171″ />
```

Still there are some search engines or other services which may very well respect them. It ***might be useful*** for a local restaurant or business to use them for SEO.

On the other hand I wonder if there are search engines which respect geolocation data which may rank you worse if you are far away. For a local business this is probably not a problem. For the corporate website of a company or and online shop this would be very harmful. Anybody having information on this?

Comment: 90% of search is Google, so unless Google supports the tag, using it isn't going to make much SEO difference.    Including meta-data is a waste of time unless you know exactly how it is going to be consumed.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It is not sure Google ignores them completely and bots using Geolocation may use them. There is not much time wasted on a setting which you do one time in the lifetime of a site. My question was primarily if it can be harmful. I agree with -tshimkus that todays way is probably schema.org.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to include location data on your pages I would recommend using https://schema.org/Organization with https://schema.org/address. <strike>It is common practice to put company contact on page footers and you easily include some Schema markup on these fields.</strike> EDIT: You can include this schema markup where you list your company's contact information (home, contact, or about page).

It's my understand that including those meta tags will not hurt your SEO for searches outside the area. I'm not sure which services (if any) will use these tags when crawling your pages.

Comment: Google says that any markup should only go on one page of your site.  Your suggestion of adding it to your sitewide footer is bad advice.  [Google: Do Not Put 'Organization' Schema Markup on Every Page - Search Engine Journal](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-do-not-put-organization-schema-markup-on-every-page/289981/)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for this information. I had not heard this before but it does make sense to save it for a single page (home or about us?). I had always cast a wide net with this schema markup and possibly some others, but I can see how this repetition may weaken its use on a more relevant page.